# Usar uma função php que está num domínio diferente

Tags: php, funções, domínio

Boas.
Preciso de usar uma função que está num ficheiro **php num domínio diferente** 
http://exx.exemplo.com/pasta/ficheio_da_funcao.php noutro site que está http://meusite.com.
O que a função faz é quando se termina um formulário envia um email para a pessoa.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Tenho o **allow_url_include** no **.ini** ativa. Já tentei com **require ( htp://exx.exemplo.com/pasta/ficheio_da_funcao.php)** e em baixo chamei a função e não deu. Já tentei também o **file_get_contents** e também não consegui.
Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer com include http://php.net/include

```
include('http://exx.exemplo.com/pasta/ficheio_da_funcao.php');
```

e no seu arquivo pode chamar a função

Comment: Não funcionou. E sei que a função funciona e a estou a chamar bem porque se eu meter o ficheiro no mesmo domino (com as devidas alterações) funciona. No entanto na minha situação não me convém ter o ficheiro no mesmo domínio...

Comment: porque não copia a função para o seu ficheiro ?